# How do I connect to TunnelBear with Kubuntu?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, kubuntu

I have followed the instructions [here](https://www.tunnelbear.com/blog/linux_support/), but I can't open the VPN connection.

The error I get is "could not connect".

Answer (score 0):

- Download the TunnelBear OpenVPN configuration from the installation guide.
- Install `network-manager-openvpn-gnome`
- Right click on the `Network` icon in the task bar > `Configure Network Connections`
- `File` > `Import VPN`
- Import one of the VPN configs from the folder you downloaded.
- Right click on the imported VPN and select `edit`.
- In the username field add your email address.
- In the password field add your password.
- Remove any text in the private key password field.